# Creating client and server sockets in the same file

Tags: sockets, tcp

I would have to design a job scheduling system which works like - users (clients) would deposit jobs (executables) to a server. I have three files - client.c, jobQ.c and server.c. The jobQ would take client requests, and send them to the server on specific timestamps (if a user wants to run job X on server Y at 07-29-2010 3:34 AM, then the jobQ would store it in a stack, and when time comes and if the server is free, it sends the job to the server).

jobQ.c would act as a server for client.c and as a client for server.c.
I have used TCP/IP sockets to program these, and the problem I am facing is while creating multiple sockets in jobQ.c. Is it possible for the same file to have client and server sockets? The error points to this line in jobQ.c:

```
sockSer = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

error: lvalue required as decrement operand
```

...when I am opening a second socket to talk to the server.

My idea is that jobQ would open different ports to listen to clients and connect to the server.

Thanks,
Sayan

Comment: there's no difference between a "client" and "server" socket. they are just sockets.. Are you sure that that call is the one getting an error? I think more code is needed in order to assist.

Comment: Post some more code around the part where it says your error is. And what's the type of `sockSer` ?

Comment: sockSer is int; and the compiler is pointing to that line specifically. Yes I would post some code soon, I too feel some other mistake might be triggering this error.

Comment: Looks like missing semicolon somewhere.

Comment: Yes, I feel ashamed since a stray '-' caused this error.